# Regex to include hyphen but not HTML code

Tags: jquery, regex

I am working with this Java Script  and am trying to figure out how to include the hyphen all the way to the end of the link.

Here is the sample link: http://www.mydomain.com:5678/cgi-bin/encoder?USER=admin&PWD=123456&VIDEO_RESOLUTION=N1280x720

And here is the code ((http://jsfiddle.net/moe3615/G9A86/)

```
// Check the main container is ready
$('#feed').ready(function(){
// Get each div
$('.content').each(function(){
// Get the content
var str = $(this).html();
// Set the regex string
var regex = /(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/ig
// Replace plain text links by hyperlinks
var replaced_text = str.replace(regex, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
// Echo link
$(this).html(replaced_text);
});
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There is a legendary post on why using regex to parse HTML is both difficult and generally a bad idea.  That said, can you explain what hyphen you are talking about?  I don't see it.

Comment: "*how to include the hyphen all the way to the end of the link.*" — What do you mean? What is the problem that you're trying to solve? What is the current result, and what is the expected result?

Comment: In the link that I have it has a hyphen at cgi-bin right after the domain name.

Comment: If you see the jsfiddle link, it only creates a link until the hyphen anything after that is not included in the link

Comment: Oh, you meant how to include **from** the hyphen to the end of the link!

Comment: So you're trying to take a plaintext "link" and turn it into an actual html link?

Comment: @user3802591: It's still unclear. Anyway, see if this helps: [How to replace plain URLs with links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Comment: Yes, precisely that. I have a page with hundreds of links that look similar to the link above, I want to turn them into a link.

Comment: `/(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.-]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/ig` just add the hyphen to the list of allowed characters, no?

Comment: Jakub for some reason when I do that if there is a </span> at the end of a link it includes that as well and it breaks the link.

Comment: You may need to escape the hyphen?

Comment: What do you mean escape the hyphen?

Comment: @JakubMichálek Is there a way to add non allowed characters? Perhaps if I eliminate the < it won't include that in the link...? I wish I knew more about Jquery... trying to learn. Thanks for your help